# Why does 'neben' take accusative case in this sentence?

Tags: preposition, accusative

Why does 'neben' take accusative case in this sentence?

> Das Sofa gehört neben den Tisch.

That is translated as:

> The sofa belongs next to the table.

Is there any sense of *movement* or *direction* in this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to common belief, it's not about movement vs no movement, but about **direction vs location.**

Often, the verb commands what is needed. Here, it's an ellipsis.

> Das Sofa gehört neben den Tisch (gestellt).

The verb *stellen* needs a direction. If you wonder about that wacky auxiliary *gehören*, it's a coupler and the whole part *neben den Tisch gestellt* is a predicative. It's where the sofa *belongs*, not where it is.

> Solch komplizierte Sachen gehören verboten.
>
> Der Erfinder der deutschen Grammatik gehört eingesperrt.

Comment: I do not see the moral impetus of your "gehört verboten" in "gehört neben den Tisch".  Claiming that the latter is an ellipsis seems dubious to me.

Comment: How about *Dieser Auflauf gehört jetzt gegessen, morgen ist er hin.* then? No moral impetus. This *gehören+Partizip II* construction in place of *werden+Partizip II* in place of a command is quite common.

Comment: The construction may be common in your region, it is not in mine. Indeed, I would claim that "gehört + Ortsangabe (Akk)" is familiar to every native speaker while "gehören+Partizip II" sounds unfamiliar to many.

Comment: What about *bleiben* then?

Comment: There seems to be no sense of *direction* in my sentence either.

Comment: There is. It's a pointing finger. You give directions where to *put* the sofa.

Answer (score 3):

If you say *X gehört neben/auf/nach Y* this usually implies that X is not at the place it belongs to.

So the sentence is asking for a change of location. Which explains why the preposition is followed by accusative, not dative.

Comment: I don't agree with the *usually implies* part. I recognize, that *x gehört nach y* expresses an expectation of the speaker (or a judgement concerning the appropriate place see, [DWDS, Bedeutung 3](https://www.dwds.de/wb/geh%C3%B6ren)), but I don't see it indicating, whether the expectation currently holds or not. In *Ein Hammer gehört in jedes Haus* I see no movement implied either. Isn't it sufficient to state, that the question would be phrased *Das Sofa gehört wohin?*